# Is the given sequence cauchy , convergent

Tags: real-analysis, convergence-divergence, cauchy-sequences

Question: Let $\\{a_n\\}$ be a sequence that satisfies
$|a_n| < 2$ ,
$|a_{n+2}-a_{n+1}| \leq \frac{1}{8}|a_{n+1}^2-a_{n}^2|$.
Then

a) $\\{a_n\\}$ is a cauchy sequence

b) $\\{a_n\\}$ is a bounded sequence

c) $\\{a_n\\}$ is not a bounded sequence

d) $\\{a_n\\}$ is not a  convergent sequence

My attempt: Since $|a_n| < 2$ for all n it is obvious that the sequence is bounded and option b is true and option c is false.

$|a_{n+2}-a_{n+1}| \leq \frac{1}{8}|a_{n+1}^2-a_{n}^2|\\
=\frac{1}{8}|a_{n+1}+a_{n}||a_{n+1}-a_{n}|$

$|a_{n+1}+a_{n}|\leq |a_{n+1}|+|a_{n}|\\\leq 2+2 =4$

$|a_{n+2}-a_{n+1}|\leq\frac{1}{2}|a_{n+1}-a_{n}|$

After these steps I don't know how to proceed. I pondered over this sum for a few days but there was no improvement beyond these steps.

Kindly help me in proving or disproving options a and d

Comment: $|a_{n+2}-a_{n+1}|\leq\frac{1}{2}|a_{n+1}-a_{n}|$ implies convergence and this has been proved  many times on this site. Search the site for a proof.

Comment: Thanks a lot . I didn't check properly

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For showing (a), let us fix $\epsilon > 0$ and find $N\in\mathbb{N}$ for Cauchy Sequence Guarantee. Assume you have two integers such that $N \leq n < n+m$.

Then,
$$
|a_{n+m} - a_{n}| \leq |a_{n+m} - a_{n+m-1}| + \cdots + |a_{n+1} - a_{n}| \leq \frac{1}{2^{n+m-1}} |a_1 - a_0| + \cdots + \frac{1}{2^{n}} |a_1 - a_0| < \frac{2^m - 1}{2^{n+m-1}} \times 4 \,.
$$

The last inequality used the fact $|a_i|<2$.

Therefore, to guarantee $|a_{n+m} - a_{n}| < \epsilon$ for any case,  $(1/2)^{N-1} \times 4 < \epsilon$ should suffice.

We can set $N$ as $1 + \lceil \log_2 (4/\epsilon) \rceil $.

For (d), do you know the notion of completeness? If so, you can get (d) directly from (a).